# No Response from Wikipedia API Call using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I have a jQuery API call that isn't giving me any response. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#form").submit(function() {

    var apiCall = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info|extracts&generator=search&callback=?&inprop=url&exsentences=3&gsrsearch=" + $("#searchTerm").val();

    $.getJSON(apiCall, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
      });

    });

  });
```

I have managed to get a response using this URL: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=" + $("#searchTerm").val() + "&callback=?"`

The problem is that I want to be able to use the URL of each page that is returned, and the above API call only gives me the title and a snippet, but no URL.

The API call that does give the URL, according to MediaWiki (verified in the sandbox) is the one in the code sample at the top: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info|extracts&generator=search&callback=?&inprop=url&exsentences=3&gsrsearch=" + $("#searchTerm").val()`.

But in my code it doesn't return anything. You can see the whole thing in action at: https://codepen.io/khaledallen/pen/VaNGMa?editors=1011

Any guidance would be appreciated (this is also my first stackoverflow question, so any guidance on question etiquette is helpful).

Comment: Both answers addressed another issue, that the page was refreshing the first time the form is submitted without pulling any data, but the URL is still not generating a response. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit your form, it actually applies the default behavior defined by the browser, meaning it's redirecting you to the form's `action` attribute. In fact, because the `action` is set to `#`, the page is simply refreshing.

In order to solve this issue, you should prevent the default behavior by simply using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
```

Adding the event object as an argument to the submit event handler (`e`), and applying the `preventDefault` method on it.

Check out this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PNgMGW?editors=1011

Comment: Thanks. That was one problem with the code. It's still not loading anything with the API URL. Just an empty object.

Comment: It does load. codepen's console does not show it for some reason. Open the developer tools and you will see the data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

1. It seems that the URL generated by the MediaWiki sandbox replaces special characters with their UTF-8 codes, but it can't read them(?). I changed all those in my URL to their regular characters and it worked fine.
2. Adding the `format=2` option helped. That's one of the JSON format options in mediawiki (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:JSON_version_2)
3. Here's the URL that returns title and URLS: `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info&generator=search&callback=?&utf8=1&formatversion=2&inprop=url&gsrsearch=Sophia&gsrprop=snippet"`

I can't get it to show URLs AND extracts/snippets, so this is only a partial solution.

Comment: And finally: the URL of a page is just the base URL + the page title. So I can use the old solution, which gave a snippet consistently. `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=" + $("#searchTerm").val() + "&callback=?` and append the page title to the base URL.